# Is it possible to convert select dropdown into horizontal months list in jQuery UI Datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker, uidatepicker

I'm building a calendar based on `jQuery UI Datepicker` with a possibility to choose date range with 3 months displayed at once. Now it looks like on screenshot: 
[image: calendar]

So I need to add a block above this calendar with 12 horizontally positioned months starting from current month. I think I need to convert default select dropdown with months to this horizontal list, but due to my little experience with JavaScript I wasn't able to even bring it to work with help of similar examples from internet.

[image: months]

When you choose a month in this block it should switch calendar to 3 chosen months. Hope you will be able to suggest me a solution.

Here is my current code:

```js
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
numberOfMonths: 3,
showButtonPanel: false,
dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
minDate: 0,
maxDate: new Date(new Date().getTime() +  365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000),
beforeShowDay: function(date) {
 var startDate = $.datepicker.parseDate('dd.mm.yy', $('#start-date').val());
 var endDate = $.datepicker.parseDate('dd.mm.yy', $('#end-date').val());
 if (startDate && endDate && startDate - endDate) {
  if (endDate <= date && date <= startDate) {
   if (startDate && date && (startDate.getTime() === date.getTime())) {
    console.log('from end to start - backward - red-start ');
    return [true, 'ui-red-end', ''];
   }
   if (endDate && date && (endDate.getTime() === date.getTime())) {
    console.log('from end to start - backward - red-end ');
    return [true, 'ui-red-start', ''];
   }
   console.log('from end to start - backward');
   return [true, 'ui-state-selected-range', ''];
  }
 }
 if (startDate <= date && date <= endDate) {
  console.log('from start to end - forward');
  if (startDate && date && (endDate.getTime() === date.getTime())) {
   console.log('from start to end - forward - red-end');
   return [true, 'ui-red-end', ''];
  }
  if (endDate && date && (startDate.getTime() === date.getTime())) {
   console.log('from start to end - forward - red-start');
   return [true, 'ui-red-start', ''];
  }
 }
 if (startDate <= date && date <= endDate) {
  console.log('from start to end');
  return [true, 'ui-state-selected-range', ''];
 }
 return [true, '', ''];
},
onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
 var startDate = $.datepicker.parseDate('dd.mm.yy', $('#start-date').val());
 var endDate = $.datepicker.parseDate('dd.mm.yy', $('#end-date').val());
  if (!startDate || endDate) {
   $('#start-date').val(dateText);
   $('.start-date-visible').text(dateText);
   $('#end-date').val('');
   $('.end-date-visible').text('');
   $(this).datepicker('option', dateText);
  } else {
   if (new Date(dateText) < startDate) {
    var sDate = $('#start-date').val();
    $('.start-date-visible').text(dateText);
    $('#start-date').val(dateText);
    $(this).datepicker('option', null);
    $('.end-date-visible').text(sDate);
    $('#end-date').val(sDate);

   } else {
    $('.end-date-visible').text(dateText);
    $('#end-date').val(dateText);
    $(this).datepicker('option', null);
   }
  }
}
}); 
// start date on default
$('#start-date').val($.datepicker.formatDate('dd.mm.yy', new Date()));
$('.start-date-visible').text($.datepicker.formatDate('dd.mm.yy', new Date()));
// end date on default
$('#end-date').val($.datepicker.formatDate('dd.mm.yy', new Date(new Date().getTime() +
  6 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)));
$('.end-date-visible').text($.datepicker.formatDate('dd.mm.yy', new Date(new Date().getTime() +
  6 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)));
```

```css
td.ui-state-selected-range:first-child a {
    border-radius: 20px 0 0 20px;
}
td.ui-state-selected-range:last-child a {
    border-radius: 0 20px 20px 0;
}
.ui-red-start a {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #F29676;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #f29676 !important;
}
.ui-red-start a:before {
    content: '';
    right: -1px;
    left: 50%;
    top: -1px;
    bottom: -1px;
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid #f29676;
    border-right: none;
    background-color: #f8c3b1;
    z-index: -1;
}
.ui-red-end a {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #F29676;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #f29676 !important;
}
.ui-red-end a:before {
    content: '';
    left: -1px;
    right: 50%;
    top: -1px;
    bottom: -1px;
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid #f29676;
    border-left: none;
    background-color: #f8c3b1;
    z-index: -1;
}

.ui-state-selected-range .ui-state-default {
    border: 1px solid #f29676 !important;
    border-left: none !important;
    border-right: none !important;
    background: #f8c3b1 !important;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="start-date" style="visibility: hidden">
<input type="text" id="end-date" style="visibility: hidden">
<span class="start-date-visible"></span> 
<span class="end-date-visible"></span>
<div id="datepicker"></div>
```

Comment: You can do with your custom `span` with `months` name like below my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps

use [destroy()](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-destroy) to set month on datepicker when you choose a month.

`$("#datepicker").datepicker("destroy");`

Then reinitialize datepicker passing selected month.

```js
var today=new Date();
var newDate;
setCalender(today.getMonth());
var today=$("#datepicker").datepicker("getDate");
var todayMonth=today.getMonth();
setMonth(todayMonth);
clickMonth();
function setCalender(defaultMonth){
$("#datepicker").datepicker("destroy");
if(today.getMonth()==defaultMonth){
newDate=new Date(today.getFullYear(),today.getMonth(),today.getDate());
}
else if(today.getMonth()>defaultMonth){
newDate=new Date(today.getFullYear()+1,defaultMonth,today.getDate());
}
else{
newDate=new Date(today.getFullYear(),defaultMonth,today.getDate());
}
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 3,
        showButtonPanel: false,
        dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
        defaultDate: newDate,
        minDate: 0,
        maxDate: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000),
        beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        var dates=new Date();

            var startDate = $.datepicker.parseDate('dd.mm.yy', $('#start-date').val());
            var endDate = $.datepicker.parseDate('dd.mm.yy', $('#end-date').val());
            if (startDate && endDate && startDate - endDate) {
                if (endDate <= date && date <= startDate) {
                    if (startDate && date && (startDate.getTime() === date.getTime())) {
                        return [true, 'ui-red-end', ''];
                    }
                    if (endDate && date && (endDate.getTime() === date.getTime())) {
                        return [true, 'ui-red-start', ''];
                    }
                    return [true, 'ui-state-selected-range', ''];
                }
            }

            if (startDate <= date && date <= endDate) {
                if (startDate && date && (endDate.getTime() === date.getTime())) {
                    return [true, 'ui-red-end', ''];
                }
                if (endDate && date && (startDate.getTime() === date.getTime())) {
                    return [true, 'ui-red-start', ''];
                }
            }

            if (startDate <= date && date <= endDate) {
                return [true, 'ui-state-selected-range', ''];
            }

            return [true, '', ''];
        },
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            var startDate = $.datepicker.parseDate('dd.mm.yy', $('#start-date').val());
            var endDate = $.datepicker.parseDate('dd.mm.yy', $('#end-date').val());

            if (!startDate || endDate) {
                $('#start-date').val(dateText);
                $('.start-date-visible').text(dateText);
                $('#end-date').val('');
                $('.end-date-visible').text('');
                $(this).datepicker('option', dateText);
            } else {
                if (new Date(dateText) < startDate) {
                    var sDate = $('#start-date').val();
                    $('.start-date-visible').text(dateText);
                    $('#start-date').val(dateText);
                    $(this).datepicker('option', null);
                    $('.end-date-visible').text(sDate);
                    $('#end-date').val(sDate);

                } else {
                    $('.end-date-visible').text(dateText);
                    $('#end-date').val(dateText);
                    $(this).datepicker('option', null);
                }
            }
        }
    }); 
    // start date on default
    $('#start-date').val($.datepicker.formatDate('dd.mm.yy', new Date()));
    $('.start-date-visible').text($.datepicker.formatDate('dd.mm.yy', new Date()));
    // end date on default
    $('#end-date').val($.datepicker.formatDate('dd.mm.yy', new Date(new Date().getTime() +
      6 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)));
    $('.end-date-visible').text($.datepicker.formatDate('dd.mm.yy', new Date(new Date().getTime() +
      6 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)));
}     
function setMonth(todayMonth){
$(".months").empty();
var month=["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"];
var after=[];
var before=[];
$.each(month,function(i,item){
 if(i>=todayMonth){
  before.push("<label data-attr='"+i+"'>"+month[i]+"</label>");
 }
 else{
  after.push("<label data-attr='"+i+"'>"+month[i]+"</label>");
 }
});
$.each(before,function(i,item){
 $(".months").append(before[i]);
});
$.each(after,function(i,item){
 $(".months").append(after[i]);
});
for(var j=0;j<3;j++){
 $(".months").find("label").eq(j).addClass("active");
}
}
function clickMonth(){
$(document).on("click","label",function(){
 var index=$(this).attr("data-attr");
 setMonth(index);
setCalender(index);
});
}
```

```css
td.ui-state-selected-range:first-child a {
    border-radius: 20px 0 0 20px;
}
td.ui-state-selected-range:last-child a {
    border-radius: 0 20px 20px 0;
}
.ui-red-start a {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #F29676;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #f29676 !important;
}
.ui-red-start a:before {
    content: '';
    right: -1px;
    left: 50%;
    top: -1px;
    bottom: -1px;
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid #f29676;
    border-right: none;
    background-color: #f8c3b1;
    z-index: -1;
}
.ui-red-end a {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #F29676;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #f29676 !important;
}
.ui-red-end a:before {
    content: '';
    left: -1px;
    right: 50%;
    top: -1px;
    bottom: -1px;
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid #f29676;
    border-left: none;
    background-color: #f8c3b1;
    z-index: -1;
}

.ui-state-selected-range .ui-state-default {
    border: 1px solid #f29676 !important;
    border-left: none !important;
    border-right: none !important;
    background: #f8c3b1 !important;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
label.active{
  font-weight:bold;
  background-color: #2795ee;
}
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-prev,.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-next{
  display:none;
}
label.active:first-child {
border-top-left-radius: 50%;
border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
}
label.active:nth-child(3n) {
border-top-right-radius: 50%;
border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
}
.months>label {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css">
<input type="text" id="start-date" style="visibility: hidden">
<input type="text" id="end-date" style="visibility: hidden">
<span class="start-date-visible"></span> 
<span class="end-date-visible"></span>
<div class="months">
</div>
<div id="datepicker"></div>
```

Comment: It works perfect, thank you! But is there a possibility to leave months panel fixed when you select months(without scrolling left/right on select) so it will show only 12 months from current to same month of next year on default and user will be able to choose from these 12 months? 3 active months will be marked not in the beginning, but on months which was chosen. If it's too much to ask I will try to do it by myself, you already helped me very much!
Also user need to be able to scroll these months panel left/right (not less than current month) by drag&drop, but this I'll try do myself.

Comment: It still require code update when user click "next" and "previous" on calendar

Comment: @Amal I meant that months will not scroll on selection change, so we have a panel with months from current(August), for example, to August of next year, but they stay this way on selection change [screenshot](https://pp.userapi.com/c841437/v841437150/1456a/C0Nrtk2m0R0.jpg)  and you can choose aother 3 months without scroll

Comment: @MikhailKolpakov sorry bro i didn't got it exactly.Just to ask months panel is not scrolling anywhere here,so where to fix this panel.Can you replicate this issue or share your development url so i can easily identify.

Comment: @Amal here you can see working example: https://sletat.ru/ (click on the elemnt as on [screenshot](https://pp.userapi.com/c841437/v841437150/14590/RPXWKIcAL4M.jpg)) but this calendar is not mine and it's not based on jQuery Datepicker I took it as example for myself.

Comment: @MikhailKolpakov Can you post it as another question

Comment: @Amal here it is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45843581/is-it-possible-to-adapt-months-panel-of-jquery-datepicker-like-in-example

Comment: @MikhailKolpakov will look into it,hope you understand it should take time

Answer (score 2):

I think, there will no default option in `Jquery-ui-calendar`, but you can make custom like below example,

Here I am setting top button with `moment.js` and on click of that increment or decrements value based on previous selected.

See below working code:-

```js
var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
];

var firstMonth = moment(new Date()).month();

function setButton() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    var classs = "months active";
    if (i > 2) {
      classs = "months";
    }
    $("#list").append("<span class='" + classs + "'>" + monthNames[firstMonth++] + "</span>");
    if (firstMonth == 12) firstMonth = 0;
  }
}

setButton();

$(document).on("click", ".ui-datepicker-next", function() {
  $(".months").remove();
  firstMonth += 1;
  if (firstMonth > 11) {
    firstMonth = 0;
  }
  setButton();
});


$(document).on("click", ".ui-datepicker-prev", function() {
  $(".months").remove();

  firstMonth -= 1;
  if (firstMonth == -1) {
    firstMonth = 11;
  }
  setButton();
});

$(document).on("click", ".months:not(.active)", function() {
  $(".ui-datepicker-next").trigger('click');
})

$("#datepicker").datepicker({
  numberOfMonths: 3,
  showButtonPanel: false,
  dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
  minDate: 0,
  maxDate: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000),
  beforeShowDay: function(date) {
    var startDate = $.datepicker.parseDate('dd.mm.yy', $('#start-date').val());
    var endDate = $.datepicker.parseDate('dd.mm.yy', $('#end-date').val());
    if (startDate && endDate && startDate - endDate) {
      if (endDate <= date && date <= startDate) {
        if (startDate && date && (startDate.getTime() === date.getTime())) {
          // console.log('from end to start - backward - red-start ');
          return [true, 'ui-red-end', ''];
        }
        if (endDate && date && (endDate.getTime() === date.getTime())) {
          //    console.log('from end to start - backward - red-end ');
          return [true, 'ui-red-start', ''];
        }
        //  console.log('from end to start - backward');
        return [true, 'ui-state-selected-range', ''];
      }
    }
    if (startDate <= date && date <= endDate) {
      //console.log('from start to end - forward');
      if (startDate && date && (endDate.getTime() === date.getTime())) {
        // console.log('from start to end - forward - red-end');
        return [true, 'ui-red-end', ''];
      }
      if (endDate && date && (startDate.getTime() === date.getTime())) {
        //  console.log('from start to end - forward - red-start');
        return [true, 'ui-red-start', ''];
      }
    }
    if (startDate <= date && date <= endDate) {
      //    console.log('from start to end');
      return [true, 'ui-state-selected-range', ''];
    }
    return [true, '', ''];
  },
  onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
    var startDate = $.datepicker.parseDate('dd.mm.yy', $('#start-date').val());
    var endDate = $.datepicker.parseDate('dd.mm.yy', $('#end-date').val());
    if (!startDate || endDate) {
      $('#start-date').val(dateText);
      $('.start-date-visible').text(dateText);
      $('#end-date').val('');
      $('.end-date-visible').text('');
      $(this).datepicker('option', dateText);
    } else {
      if (new Date(dateText) < startDate) {
        var sDate = $('#start-date').val();
        $('.start-date-visible').text(dateText);
        $('#start-date').val(dateText);
        $(this).datepicker('option', null);
        $('.end-date-visible').text(sDate);
        $('#end-date').val(sDate);

      } else {
        $('.end-date-visible').text(dateText);
        $('#end-date').val(dateText);
        $(this).datepicker('option', null);
      }
    }
  }
});
// start date on default
$('#start-date').val($.datepicker.formatDate('dd.mm.yy', new Date()));
$('.start-date-visible').text($.datepicker.formatDate('dd.mm.yy', new Date()));
// end date on default
$('#end-date').val($.datepicker.formatDate('dd.mm.yy', new Date(new Date().getTime() +
  6 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)));
$('.end-date-visible').text($.datepicker.formatDate('dd.mm.yy', new Date(new Date().getTime() +
  6 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)));
```

```css
td.ui-state-selected-range:first-child a {
  border-radius: 20px 0 0 20px;
}

td.ui-state-selected-range:last-child a {
  border-radius: 0 20px 20px 0;
}

.ui-red-start a {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #F29676;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #f29676 !important;
}

.ui-red-start a:before {
  content: '';
  right: -1px;
  left: 50%;
  top: -1px;
  bottom: -1px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #f29676;
  border-right: none;
  background-color: #f8c3b1;
  z-index: -1;
}

.ui-red-end a {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #F29676;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #f29676 !important;
}

.ui-red-end a:before {
  content: '';
  left: -1px;
  right: 50%;
  top: -1px;
  bottom: -1px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #f29676;
  border-left: none;
  background-color: #f8c3b1;
  z-index: -1;
}

.ui-state-selected-range .ui-state-default {
  border: 1px solid #f29676 !important;
  border-left: none !important;
  border-right: none !important;
  background: #f8c3b1 !important;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.months {
  padding: 10px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

.months.active {
  background: #ffc2c2;
}

.months:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" />
<input type="text" id="start-date" style="visibility: hidden">
<input type="text" id="end-date" style="visibility: hidden">
<span class="start-date-visible"></span>
<span class="end-date-visible"></span>
<div id="list">
</div>
<div id="datepicker"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, Yogen, for your suggestion! It was also helful to understand how it works!